# Extra White Space On the Left Side of the Screen

Tags: html, css

Even though I have removed the padding and the margin for the lower_content div, I'm still getting this thin white space on the left side of screen...It's like there's an invisible margin that I just can't find anywhere.  MY content reaches the right side of the screen just fine, but not the left.

Please, help me find the problem...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title>My name here</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleForFullPage.css" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

    <div class="side_banner">
        <nav>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_me_FP.html" >ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio_FP.html" >PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_me_FP.html" >CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <hr/>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="name_div">
        <h1>My name here</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="lower_content">
        <p>LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
            <br/>
    LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
        <br/>
            LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
        </p>
    </div>  


</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: comfortaa;
        src: url(Comfortaa-Regular.ttf);
    }


html { 
  background: url(meAndTheOcean.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



.side_banner{
    /*font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;*/
    font-family: comfortaa;

    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 26.3999996185303px;

    background-color:transparent;


    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0% 2% 2% 0%;
}


.side_banner nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;


}



.side_banner nav ul li{

}
.side_banner nav a:link, .side_banner nav a:visited{
    color: white;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*padding: 10px 25px;*/
    padding: 10px;
}

.side_banner nav a:hover, .side_banner nav a:active, .side_banner nav .active a:link,
.side_banner nav .active a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: orange;
    /*background-color: 1C6BA0;*/
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

}

.main_content{
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 2% 2% 2% ;
    width: 70%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    color:white;

    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

}

.name_div{
    font-family:comfortaa;
    color: white;

    text-align: center;

    width: 300px;
    height:200px;

    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-110px 0 0 -150px;
}

.lower_content{
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 650px;
    width:100%;

    background-color:white;

    overflow-x:hidden;


    color:black;
    font-size:20;

    margin: 0% 0% 0% 0% ;
    padding: 0;

    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

}
```

Comment: apply the `html` element styles to `body` element as well. Like `html, body { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<body>` has its own `margin` of `8px` by default.

Simply define the rule

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Or, as stated in the comments, use a collective rule for both `body` and `html`:

```css
html, body {
  …
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem! Is there any way to now keep it from scrolling horizontally? For some reason, not all of the content fits in one full window, and the page scrolls horizontally

Comment: I found the problem...it was when I made lower content width: 100%...why is that?

Comment: @mnot I have no idea about the horizontal scrolling; I can’t reproduce it…

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned up your cod please check this it may help you

```css
@font-face {
        font-family: comfortaa;
        src: url(Comfortaa-Regular.ttf);
    }
body { 
  background: #6fa5ae; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.side_banner{
    font-family: comfortaa;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 26px;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0% 2% 2% 0%;
}
.side_banner nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.side_banner nav a:link, .side_banner nav a:visited{
    color: white;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.side_banner nav a:hover, .side_banner nav a:active, .side_banner nav .active a:link,
.side_banner nav .active a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: orange;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.main_content{
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 2% 2% 2% ;
    width: 70%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.name_div{
    font-family:comfortaa;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    float: right;
}

.lower_content{
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:92%;
    margin: 2%;
    background-color:white;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    color:black;
    font-size:20;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="side_banner">
        <nav>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_me_FP.html" >ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio_FP.html" >PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_me_FP.html" >CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <hr/>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="name_div">
        <h1>My name here</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="lower_content">
        <p>LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
            <br/>
    LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
        <br/>
            LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set list-style to none for ul, the left margin keeped for the item mark still exists. You just need to overwrite the left margin of the ul.

Answer (score 0):

See here.

```css
@font-face {
        font-family: comfortaa;
        src: url(Comfortaa-Regular.ttf);
    }
body{
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html { 
  background: url(meAndTheOcean.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



.side_banner{
    /*font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;*/
    font-family: comfortaa;

    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 26.3999996185303px;

    background-color:transparent;


    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0% 2% 2% 0%;
}


.side_banner nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;


}



.side_banner nav ul li{
background:#000;
}
.side_banner nav a:link, .side_banner nav a:visited{
    color: white;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*padding: 10px 25px;*/
    padding: 10px;
}

.side_banner nav a:hover, .side_banner nav a:active, .side_banner nav .active a:link,
.side_banner nav .active a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: orange;
    /*background-color: 1C6BA0;*/
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

}

.main_content{
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 2% 2% 2% ;
    width: 70%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    color:white;

    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

}

.name_div{
    font-family:comfortaa;
    color: white;

    text-align: center;

    width: 300px;
    height:200px;

    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-110px 0 0 -150px;
}

.lower_content{
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 650px;
    width:100%;

    background-color:white;

    overflow-x:hidden;


    color:black;
    font-size:20;

    margin: 0% 0% 0% 0% ;
    padding: 0;

    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="side_banner">
        <nav>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_me_FP.html" >ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio_FP.html" >PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_me_FP.html" >CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <hr/>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="name_div">
        <h1>My name here</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="lower_content">
        <p>LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
            <br/>
    LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
        <br/>
            LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
LOWER CONTENT! LOWER CONTENT! 
        </p>
    </div>
```